# KML/Fusion Tables - line is always red

Tags: google-maps, kml, google-fusion-tables

I've been playing around with the Fusion Tables/Google Maps stuff to create some flight paths between different places but I can't figure out how to style the lines correctly.

This is an example KML that I imported:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document>
  <name>LineStyle.kml</name>
  <open>1</open>
  <Style id="linestyleExample">
    <LineStyle>
      <color>00FF00</color>
      <width>4</width>
      <gx:labelVisibility>1</gx:labelVisibility>
    </LineStyle>
  </Style>
  <Placemark>
    <name>LineStyle Example</name>
    <styleUrl>#linestyleExample</styleUrl>
    <LineString>
      <extrude>1</extrude>
      <tessellate>1</tessellate>
     <coordinates>-0.47364383,51.824664,0.0 -122.364152,37.824322,0.0</coordinates>
    </LineString>
  </Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

And it draws the line correctly but it's always red no matter what value I put inside the LineStyle section.

Anyone got any ideas how to get a different colour? I've tried everything I can think of but I'm stuck!

Thanks in advance,
Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fusion Tables does not import style information, you have to re-style using the Fusion Tables interface

Comment: Oh really!? I didn't know that. I was hoping to be able to put different styling on the different lines that I want to draw - am I right in thinking it's not possible to do that then?

Comment: You can style them in FusionTables using the User Interface (in Visualize:Map, click on Configure Styles).  You can configure up to 5 styles dynamically in the Google Maps API v3 on a (single) FusionTablesLayer.

Answer (score 1):

You can style them (polylines, polygons, and markers) in FusionTables using the User Interface [(in Visualize:Map, click on Configure Styles)](http://support.google.com/fusiontables/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=185991). It is easiest if you put style information in a column (unless you want them all the same)

You can also configure up to 5 styles dynamically in the Google Maps API v3 on a (single) FusionTablesLayer.

Comment: That is another question.